# Issue with terra::mask

Tags: r, maps, terra

[image]I try to mask the mapenter image description here in the rectangles with the borders of Switzerland.

```
 str(swissmask)
S4 class 'SpatVector' [package "terra"]
> swissmask
 class       : SpatVector 
 geometry    : polygons 
 dimensions  : 1, 4  (geometries, attributes)
 extent      : 2485203, 2834035, 1075283, 1295864  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
 coord. ref. : CH1903+ / LV95 (EPSG:2056) 
 names       :   ID0                       ID1   ID2   ID3
 type        : <chr>                     <chr> <chr> <chr>
 values      :     1 Schweiz/Suisse/Svizzera/~ Area1 Area1
```

and the map itself

```
[![> str(x)
S4 class 'SpatRaster' \[package "terra"\]
Warning messages:
1: In class(object) <- "environment" :
  Setting class(x) to "environment" sets attribute to NULL; result will no longer be an S4 object
2: In class(object) <- "environment" :
  Setting class(x) to "environment" sets attribute to NULL; result will no longer be an S4 object

    > x][1]][1]
class       : SpatRaster 
dimensions  : 1141, 1926, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
resolution  : 200, 200  (x, y)
extent      : 479900, 865100, 73900, 302100  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : CH1903 / LV03 (EPSG:21781) 
source(s)   : memory
name        :      V3 
min value   :  193.00 
max value   : 4556.63
```

using the code

```
x <- import("C:/Users/User/Documents/R/Karten/DHM200.csv", setclass = "tibble") %>% 
  mutate(across(everything(), ~ as.double(.))) %>% 
  rast(type = "xyz", crs = cdref) %>% 
  mask(swissmask, inverse = T)
```

That does not impact the result. What is it I do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These two objects have different coordinate reference systems, and so very different numerical extents:

```
extent      : 2485203, 2834035, 1075283, 1295864  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : CH1903+ / LV95 (EPSG:2056) 

extent      : 479900, 865100, 73900, 302100  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : CH1903 / LV03 (EPSG:21781)
```

If you use `project` to transform your polygons to the coordinate system of the raster then this should work. Hard to confirm without your data, but that's the usual solution.

Note that if I `mask` with two rasters with different coordinate systems I get a warning message, but I don't get one for masking a raster with a vector. This might be worth reporting.

Comment: Thank you very much - I was so sure it was the same Coord - System!